# Using grep with suffix

Tags: linux

How I can use grep with a certain suffix? I want to display the name of the user that is connected now which the first name is ending with the letter "a". The names are formatting like that: firstName.lastName.
My command:

```
finger | awk '{print $1}' | grep \*a.\*
```

But doesn't work...

Comment: Doesn't `finger | awk '{print $1}'` return the usernames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` also has special meaning in grep. Try this:

```
grep '.*a\..*'
```

Comment: Works. Thank you

Comment: Please set the answer as accepted. Thanks. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: One more question if you don't mind.... I want to display only the users which their name is starting with "a". I tryed like that:  who | awk '{print $1}' | grep -w 'a.*'
But it's not right...